# Is there any way to speed up a query using a CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, case

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY columnName, CASE WHEN columnName IS NULL THEN id ELSE 0 END
```

The purpose of the `CASE` statement in the `GROUP` statement is to prevent rows with `null` in columnName (the column value I'm using to group rows together) from being grouped together. I only want to group together rows that have non-null values in `columnName`.

The problem is that the `CASE` statement increases the execution time of the query from `0.09s` to `0.854s`, an increase of about 10x.

Using `EXPLAIN`, I can see that without the `CASE` statement, an index for `columnName` is used, but with the `CASE` statement no index is used, which I'm assuming is why the query becomes so much slower?

Is there any way to prevent the `CASE` statement from slowing the query down so much? For example, is it possible to index the `CASE` statement?

I'm very inexperienced with SQL, so the only solution I can think of is to create another column, named something like `columnName_or_id`, and to include logic in my software that makes another query after inserting the row to put the `id` into `columnName_or_id`, and if later a value is inserted into `columnName` to also insert that value into `columnName_or_id` (hence the name of the new column, as it either contains the  row `id` or the `columnName` value). That would eliminate the need for the `CASE` statement in the query.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be faster to do a `union all` in this case:

```
(SELECT id
 FROM table
 WHERE columnName is not null
 GROUP BY columnName
)
union all
(select id
 from table
 where columnName is null
)
```

If `where columnName is not null` prevents the use of the index, then try `having columnName is not null`.

Comment: Don't UNIONs break indexing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey . . . Not to my knowledge.  Appropriate indexes should be used on the subqueries.

Comment: This is a definite improvement. It decreases the execution time to `0.244s` -- still almost 3x slower than the original query, but 3.5x faster than the `CASE` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
GROUP BY coalesce(columnName, id)
```

Comment: I just tried it and the execution time is `0.808s`, so no improvement, unfortunately.